# Android app keeps crashing when deleting a text

Tags: android, crash

I'm new to developing in Android Studio. I'm creating a sales app, and when I clear the text on "txtpay" the app crashes itself.

Android Studio keeps telling me that the crash occurred in line:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
int subtotal = Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
int pay = Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
int bal = pay - subtotal;
ed6.setText(String.valueOf(bal));
```

I tried to create a Clear button for it but it still crashing.

Using this code:

```
 clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ed5.setText("");
                ed6.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Here is my full code:

```
package com.example.MPOS;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Sales extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> data3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    private TableLayout table;
    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6;
    Button add,clear;
    ImageView rdash;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales);

        ed1 = findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
        ed2 = findViewById(R.id.ItemPrice);
        ed3 = findViewById(R.id.ItemQuantity);
        ed4 = findViewById(R.id.txtsub);
        ed5 = findViewById(R.id.txtpay);
        ed6 = findViewById(R.id.txtbalance);
        add = findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
        rdash = findViewById(R.id.Left_Icon);
        clear = findViewById(R.id.BtnClear);


        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ed5.setText("");
                ed6.setText("");
            }
        });

        rdash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Left_Icon = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(Left_Icon);
                finish();
            }
        });



        ed5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int subtotal = Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
                int pay = Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
                int bal = pay - subtotal;
                ed6.setText(String.valueOf(bal));

            }
        });



        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                add();
            }
        });




    }

        public void add()

        {
            int tot;

            String prodname = ed1.getText().toString();
            int price = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
            tot = price * qty;

            data.add(prodname);
            data1.add(String.valueOf(price));
            data2.add(String.valueOf(qty));
            data3.add(String.valueOf(tot));

            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
            TableRow row = new TableRow (this);
            TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t3 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t4 = new TextView(this);

            String total;

            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i< data.size(); i ++)
            {
                String pname = data.get(i);
                String pprice = data1.get(i);
                String pqty = data2.get(i);
                total = data3.get(i);

                t1.setText(pname);
                t2.setText(pprice);
                t3.setText(pqty);
                t4.setText(total);

                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(data3.get(i).toString());

            }

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);
            row.addView(t3);
            row.addView(t4);
            table.addView(row);

                ed4.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                ed3.setText("");

                ed1.requestFocus();


        }

}
```

Comment: Please share stack trace of crash

Comment: Please add crash error

Comment: When you call `ed5.setText("");` you are trying to do `Integer.parseInt("")`. This will cause `NumberFormatException`. Better way is to set "0", or add `try catch` block on it.

Comment: Heres the crash error:                                                                         
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.MPOS, PID: 8679
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.MPOS.Sales$2.afterTextChanged(Sales.java:79)